# :target modalDialog not opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a menu for slide links (using slick slider):

```
<ul class="links">
    <li><a href="#openModal">Slide 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#openModal">Slide 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#openModal">Slide 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#openModal">Slide 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#openModal">Slide 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#openModal">Slide 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Clicking on any link opens a modal dialog with the correct slide open (using CSS `:target`):

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
<div class="modalBox">
<section class="slider">
    <div>slide1</div> <!-- slides -->
    <div>slide2</div>
    <div>slide3</div>
    <div>slide4</div>
    <div>slide5</div>
    <div>slide6</div>
</section>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS for modal:

```
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align:center;
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Full JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/j7tua7rL/18/

Unfortunately the modal dialog does not open when I click on any of the links. Why is that so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have check your code. i found that the issue with jQuery. THe  `e.preventDefault();` is causing the issue :

Here is what work for me:

```
var $slideshow = $(".slider").slick();

$('.links').on('click', 'a', function( e ) {
    var slideIndex = $(this).closest('li').index();
    $slideshow.slick( 'slickGoTo', slideIndex );
});
```

Here is Updated http://jsfiddle.net/j7tua7rL/19/

Answer (score 2):

You have to set special attributes on the links:

```
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#openModal"
```

Edit:
Your modal javascript is conflicting with the sliders code

```
$('.links').on('click', 'a', function( e ) {
    var slideIndex = $(this).closest('li').index();
    $slideshow.slick( 'slickGoTo', parseInt( slideIndex ) );
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

In order to make it work you will have to use another class, create a `button` inside the `li` or a wrapper around the `a`. You could try removing the preventDefault which is preventing the a to achieve the target. Or just use the data attributes.